# DTLS. 141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small

Tags: qt, ssl, dtls

I have two Qt-based applications (client and server) which use DTLS and TLS connections. That works fine on Ubuntu and Windows 10. Now i have tried to build the server's part for a raspberry pi 4 (raspbian). TLS works fine but a DTLS handshake stops with error.
On server side (raspbian):

> 14102410:SSL routines:dtls1_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

On client (Ubuntu 20):

> 141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small

The client's error is quite popular and i have found many solutions fix that (add 2 string into the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf) but that doesn't affect

Comment: After long time of tests i have established connection. Raspberry uses DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 cipher (dont know whay). I set "m_serverConfiguration.setCiphers({QSslCipher("ECDHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305")})" and that works but that is temporary solution

Comment: By the way, i have tried to connect from console: `openssl s_client -dtls1_2 -connect 192.168.0.103:3000 -psk 70736b -psk_identity 6eccf762dfb624c9b915f4b34238431c`. And see similar error